# Erro de validação com Spring MVC em Entity aninhada

Tags: java, spring-mvc

E ai galera tudo bem? Comecei a estudar Spring recentemente pelos cursos da AlgaWorks e ao andamento do curso me deparei com um problema em um projeto a parte que estou desenvolvendo.

Tenho um entity Escola que possui as seguintes características:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotNull(message = "Código INEP é obrigatório")
@Column(name = "codigo_inep", unique = true)
private Integer codigoINEP;

@NotEmpty(message = "Nome é obrigatória")
@Size(max = 100, message = "O nome não pode conter mais de 100 caracteres")
@Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
private String nome;

@Column(name = "telefone", length = 16)
private String telefone;

@Column(name = "celular", length = 16)
private String celular;

@Email(message = "E-mail inválido")
@Column(length = 80)
private String email;
```

E a minha entity Endereco está da seguinte forma:

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Logradouro é obrigatório")
@Column(length = 80)
private String logradouro;

@Column(length = 10)
private String numero;

@Column(length = 80)
private String complemento;

@NotEmpty(message = "Bairro é obrigatório")
@Column(length = 60)
private String bairro;

@NotEmpty(message = "Município é obrigatório")
@Column(length = 60, nullable = false)
private String municipio;

@NotEmpty(message = "CEP é obrigatório")
@Column(length = 10)
private String cep;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(length = 2, nullable = false)
private Uf uf;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(length = 8)
private Localizacao localizacao;

@Column(length = 60)
private String distrito;
```

No meu controle o método mapeado para acessar a view de CadastroEscola está da seguinte forma:

```
@RequestMapping("/nova")
public ModelAndView nova() {

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView(CADASTRO_VIEW);
    Escola escola = new Escola();
    escola.setEndereco(new Endereco());
    mv.addObject(escola);

    return mv;
}
```

E o método mapeado para salvar está dessa maneira:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String salvar(@Validated Escola escola, Errors erros, RedirectAttributes attributes) {

    if (erros.hasErrors()) {
        return CADASTRO_VIEW;
    }

    escolas.save(escola);

    attributes.addFlashAttribute("mensagem", "Escola salva com sucesso!");

    return "redirect:/escola/nova";
}
```

Utilizei esse trecho de código para listar os erros na minha View CadastroEscola:

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}">

    <div th:each="detailedError : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}">
        <span th:text="${detailedError.message}"></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

E esse atributo em cada input para deixar o input vermelho caso tenha algum erro de validação:

```
<div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('nome')} ? 'has-error'" >

                    <label for="nome" class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Nome</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-4" >
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" th:field="*{nome}" placeholder="Informe o seu nome" />
                    </div>

                </div>
```

No input nome caso não insira nenhum valor aparece o erro e o campo fica vermelho, mas no input cep abaixo não aparece, abaixo segue o mesmo:

```
<div class="form-group" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('endereco.cep')} ? 'has-error'" >

                    <label for="cep" class="col-sm-2 control-label"  >CEP</label>

                    <div class="col-sm-2" >
                        <input type="text" class="form-control js-cep" id="cep" th:field="*{endereco.cep}" placeholder="00000-000" />
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Como faço para pegar esses erros de validação do entity Escola e exibir na minha página, desde já agradeço. Vlw galera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na entity `Escola` que você colocou não há um atributo `Endereco`. Você esqueceu de colocá-lo?

Caso haja um atributo endereco na classe `Escola`, adicione a anotação `@Valid`:

```
@NotNull
@Valid
private Endereco endereco;
```

Comment: Bom dia Felipe Marinho havia colocado sim, só esqueci de mostra ele no corpo do entity Escola acima. Agora está funcionando corretamente, muito obrigado.